# Angular 2 *ngFor recreates components on every change check

Tags: angular, typescript, ngfor

I have two nested `*ngFor` loops, one iterates through libraries and the other one iterates through all items of this library, there is an angular component dedicated to each item.

Now the problem is, that these item components get recreated on every change check of angular, which I noticed by placing a logger into the `ngOnInit()` handler of the item component. This logger gets called whenever I change anything on the page, causing the state of the component to get reset and all changes to it get lost, so I cannot modify the state of the component, which completely breaks the functionality of my application.

I tried to work around this by using `trackBy: trackByFn` but that didn't help either.

**Container**:

```
<div *ngFor="let lib of libraries">
  <div *ngIf="lib.components.length" class="groupContainer" [class.closed]="!libraryIsOpened(lib)">
    <div class="title flex flex-row" (click)="toggleLibrary(lib)">
      <p>{{ lib.name === '__none' ? 'No Library' : lib.name }} ({{ lib.components.length }})</p>
      <div class="flex flex-grow"></div>
      <i class="mdi mdi-chevron-up iconClose"></i>
      <i class="mdi mdi-chevron-down iconOpen"></i>
    </div>
    <div class="content">
      <app-component-list-item *ngFor="let c of components; trackBy: trackByFn"
                     class="flex"
                     [component]="c">
      </app-component-list-item>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

**List Item**:

```
import ...


@Component({
  selector: 'app-component-list-item',
  templateUrl: './component-list-item.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./component-list-item.component.scss']
})
export class ComponentListItemComponent implements OnInit {

  @Input() component: PipelineComponent

  constructor(private el: ElementRef, private nodeCreator: NodeCreationService) {
  }

  ngOnInit() {
    console.log('init')
  }

  trackByFn(index, item) {
    return this.component.componentID
  }
}
```

Comment: Can you post code where you're creating libraries model? Or maybe you can create repro case on stackblitz

Comment: is the libraries model changing if you change anything on the page , this might be the only issue

Comment: The libraries is an array which gets loaded from the backend once the page loads, I also tried to hardcode it, but the issue was still there even with the hardcoded json

Comment: Nevermind, I found the error

Comment: Shouldn't your trackByFn be on your parent component and not in your ComponentListItemComponent?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without seeing more of your code, it's hard to know for sure.  But I suspect it's because `libraries` is changing (are you using Redux? that would require the top-level `libraries` list to change it any element or element's property has changed), and so the Angular change detections sees that it has changed (and isn't smart enough to know that the elements inside are the same) and so recreates new components for each of its elements.  If that's the case, then you should store a mutable copy of libraries in the parent component, and change it in-place, so that Angular doesn't think the whole thing has changed when one element has changed.

Comment: So the object itself didnt change, but the actual reference changed, because the libraries array was returned by a getter function and some filter method, which created a new reference on every iteration. You pointed me to the solution!